# Is it possible to view a PDF file from an URL link using Quick Look Framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, quicklook

As the title says, I need to display a PDF file stored in a remote server without downloading it on the device just by using an URL link. Is it possible to do it by using the `Quick Look` framework?

I am using this code below:

```
- (void)openDocument {
    QLPreviewController *docPreviewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
    [docPreviewController setDataSource:self];
    [docPreviewController setDelegate:self];
    [docPreviewController setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:sender.tag];
    [self.destinationViewController presentViewController:docPreviewController animated:true completion:nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
    return 1;
}

- (id<QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://www.domain.com/file.pdf"];
}
```

But I have this problem in the console:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController: invalid scheme https.  Only the file scheme is supported.
```

Comment: Try this blog. it might be helpful for you http://kratinmobile.com/blog/index.php/document-preview-in-ios-with-quick-look-framework/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have resolved by using `UIDocumentInteractionController`

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *viewer = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
viewer.delegate = self;
[viewer presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

**No it's not supported by current QLFramework.**
All quicklook supported items should conforms to "QLPreviewItem" protocol. 
According to QL's document

> The methods in the QLPreviewItem protocol are also declared as a category on the NSURL class. As a result, you can use NSURL objects directly as preview items—provided that you want to use the default titles of those items.

QLPreviewItem protocol contains previewItemURL attribute, which is a URL type. But the document tells us directly:

> The value of this property must be a file-type URL.

In other words, **it doesn't accept other url schema.**